# Problems with DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable in an Emulator

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have en Windows 8 mobile application running in an Emulator. I have turned on "Enable network emulation" and sset Network Speed to "No Network".

When I start my application I have as expected no connection to the Network. But how do I test for that?

I have tried `DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable` and `DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled`

`DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled` is always false since i'm running in an Emulator, but I expected  `DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable to be false as well.

So can I

1. Detect that I have no network (due to my emulator settings)

   or
2. Setup my emulator so that DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable == false

Answer (score 0):

You gotta set up your emulator as for the network connection.

You'll have to look into this to troubleshoot.

[Troubleshooting the Windows Phone 8 Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681694(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: "You gotta set up your emulator as for the network connection."

The question was how?

Comment: you could find it, if you go through the link which i've mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but can you try:

```
var IsNetworkConnected = new NetworkInterfaceList().Any(info => info.InterfaceState == ConnectState.Connected);
```

Comment: Then, "No Network" in the emulator speed just means that the speed is very close to zero, but not totally disconnected. Imagine you are in a tunnel or in a theater.